# Rendering pagination with Kaminari in Sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq, kaminari

I have a series of queries that are very heavy and could take a while to execute.

I queue a background job with the query when a page load is requested and broadcast the results to the user with ActionCable.

The results are rendered in a partial by `ApplicationController.render` and include kaminari pagination.

When I try to render pagination links in the partial

`= paginate result_set, params: {controller: 'model_query', action: 'show'}`

an error is thrown:

`ActionView::Template::Error: Devise could not find the`Warden::Proxy`instance on your request environment.`

I'm not sure why devise needs to be instantiated for kaminari to render the pagination links

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as you, when I tried to use `ApplicationController.render` to render the view that I want to pass to the action cable. Now I am using `ApplicationController.render_with_signed_in_user` from the atricle below, this solutions solve my problem. Hope it works with you.

https://qiita.com/littleFeet/items/dd3dfe713e130b969fcc

PS* the article is in japanese